# Pandas error TypeError: data type not understood

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to slice a pandas dataframe using boolean indexing code like:

```
subset[subset.bl.str.contains("Stoke City")]
```

The column `bl` is of 'object' dtype.

Yet when I run it, I get an error: `TypeError: data type not understood`

How do I fix this?

UPDATE:

I tried using:

```
subset[subset.bl.astype(str).str.contains("Stoke City")]
```

But that gave: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)`

I then tried fixing that with:

```
subset.bl = subset.bl.str.encode("utf-8")
```

That seemed to work, but I got the same error: `'data type not understood error'`

when I again tried:

```
subset[subset.bl.astype(str).str.contains("Stoke City")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try cast to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), because `object` can be something else as `string`:

```
subset[subset.bl.astype(str).str.contains("Stoke City")]
```

You can check `type` of first value by:

```
type(subset.ix[0, 'bl'])
```

EDIT:

You can try:

```
subset[subset.bl.str.encode("utf-8").str.contains("Stoke City")]
```

Or:

```
subset['bl'] = subset.bl.str.encode("utf-8")
subset[subset.bl.str.contains("Stoke City")]
```

Comment: How does it work? If not, I can remove answer. Btw, unicode problems are really bad :(

Comment: It hasn't worked, unfortunately. However, don't remove your answer as I wasn't aware of the way you've tried to solve the problem. I appreciate your help in trying. :) It might also help others.

Comment: I even tried to check what datatypes existed in the frame but set(corpus.bl.apply(type)) just returned {unicode}.

Comment: What is souurce of `data`? `csv`, `excel`? Do you use last version of pandas? What is your version of python - 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm running Pandas 0.18.0 on Python 2.7

Comment: Is possible upgrade to python 3? My experience with this upgrade is nice - only now I have to write more brackets e.g. in `print ()`  and some `range` need convert to `list`...

Comment: I've been thinking about it, but just worried about the upgrade process and then forgetting to install modules. Can you suggest a good step-by-step guide?

Comment: @elksie5000 https://python-3-for-scientists.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python3_transition_guide.html